# Why are some glibc functions included in header files and some are in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, glibc

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 float a = std::min(1.0, 2.0);
 printf("hello\n");
 return 0; 
}
```

Compiling the above with `-g` and using gdb we can see that `std::min` is part of the final binary, provided by `<iostream>` and not in a shared lib:

#### /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h

```
template<typename _Tp>
_GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
inline const _Tp&
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
{
// concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_Tp>)
//return __b < __a ? __b : __a;
  if (__b < __a)
    return __b;
  return __a;
}
```

However `printf` is linked dynamically and is part of the libc runtime, and does not exist within my final binary.

Why isn't `std::min` part of the runtime libc also?

Comment: For one, a template cannot be part of the shared library, but must be in the header

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't std::min part of the runtime libc also?

Firstly, libc is an implementation of the C standard library, and it doesn't have the namespace `std` because it is the standard library for the C language which is a language doesn't have namespaces.

Secondly, the C standard doesn't specify that the standard library has such function as `min`, so there is no reason for a C standard library implementation to provide such function.

---

In case you are wondering why the `std::min` template from the C++ standard library is compiled into your binary, it is because the instance of that template is an **inline** function.

Comment: even if it wasn't inline it would still be compiled into my binary, as the function definition of `min` would be part of my compilation unit (included by header).